# Можно ли получить ссылку на вершину многоугольника и удалить эту вершину?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, polygon

На карте нарисован многоугольник. Пользователь рисует второй. Нужно удалить те вершины из первого многоугольника, которые попадают во второй.

Задача вроде кажется простой, но никак не могу найти способа получить как объект (набор объектов) вершины многоугольника. Т.е. координаты получаю без проблем:

```
MyPolygon.geometry.getCoordinates(0);
```

или так:

```
MyPolygon.geometry.get(0)[index];
```

А как получить ссылку на объект - вершина многоугольника - не понимаю. Или нет таких объектов?

И можно ли как-то удалять заданные вершины (по индексу или координатам) или нужно удалять весь многоугольник, и рисовать новый без "удалённых" точек?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ссылку на объект можно получить с помощью getChildGeometry https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/geometry.Polygon-docpage/ и удалить с помощью remove https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/ILinearRingGeometryAccess-docpage/

```
myGeoObject.geometry.getChildGeometry(0).remove(2);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bghy3q2z/

Comment: Спасибо. Вроде сработало. Написал так:

for(i=MyPolugon.geometry.getCoordinates()[0].length-1;i>0;i--)
    if(Eraser.geometry.contains(MyPolugon.geometry.getChildGeometry(0).get(i)))
        MyPolugon.geometry.getChildGeometry(0).remove(i);

Однако, нашел решение и без getChildGeometry:

for(i=points[0].length-1;i>0;i--)
    if(Eraser.geometry.contains(points[0][i]))
        points[0].splice(i, 1);
MyPolugon.geometry.setCoordinates(points);